# How to deploy database pods in a microservice architecture in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, caching, cloud, microservices

I am new to both microservices and Kubernetes. I am working on a side project (for learning purpose) in which I have 5 microservices. 3 of these microservices use DB only to store TXN data. But this data can be huge. Remaining 2 talk to DB for CRUD operations. I have following doubts. Can anyone please help me out ?

1. On worker node, Can I deploy both Application and DB pods ? I mean is this approach scalable ?
2. I read that we should not keep DB container and Application Container inside one pod because it creates tight coupling. Is this correct?
3. If I create a cluster of DB on separate node, where do I keep my cache pod ? Will it be a container inside application pod or as a separate pod on worker node or some other approach ? My microservices can be geographically distributed.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been learning docker and k8s for the past 6 months and working on the k8s project. Based on my experience, deploying applications and DB pods in one worker node is not scalable. Because deploying in different nodes will help scalability independently and flexibility.
But you can deploy in one node like when using Minikube for development purposes.

Regarding the cache pod question, you can use a sidecar container like Redis along with the application pod. By following this approach cache can be placed close to the application which gives relatively fast access to cache data.

You can check our architecture for application deployment and Redis cache Implementation here: https://github.com/wso2/apk

Side car container pattern explanation: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/kubernetes-learn-sidecar-container-pattern-6d8c21f873d

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Thumilan. I have one doubt in sidecar pattern. In a case where cache data is going to be same for microservices, is it recommended to use sidecar pattern. If each pod is having individual cache container, isn't it like wasting resources due to duplication ? What should be the preferred approach in this case ?

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to use multiple containers in a pod here; that's really a specialized setup.  If you need to scale up to 10 replicas under load, do you also want 10 independent Redises?

Comment: @DavidMaze No cache data is same for 2 services. That can be managed by few instances as well. That's what my thought as well. Using cache for each pod might not be applicable in my case.